# Google drive access token issue details

Tags: google-drive-api, access-token

I have to upload file directly on google drive on drupal.I have created a custom module for this.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessType('online');
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
//parameter got from code

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
}

if (isset($params['code'])) {
    try{
        $client->authenticate($params['code']);       //client Authenticate with OAuth2 code
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";      //Exception Caught
    }
    $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

//access token value saved in session
//print_r($_SESSION['upload_token']); "<br>";
if (isset($_SESSION['upload_token']) && $_SESSION['upload_token']) {
    //$about = $service->about->get();
    //echo '<pre>12';print_r($about);
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['upload_token']);
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
        //drupal_goto('http://localhost/drupal/drivefile/form');
        //drupal_set_message(t('Access Token expired.'), 'error');
    }
} 
else {
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

/************************************************
If we're signed in then lets try to upload our
file.
************************************************/
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    // Now lets try and send the metadata as well using multipart!
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setTitle($_SESSION['filename']);
    try{
        $fileupload = "public://" . $_SESSION['filename'];
        $data = file_get_contents($fileupload);
        $result2 = $service->files->insert(
            $file, array(
                'data' => $data,
                'mimeType' => $_SESSION['mimetype'],
                'uploadType' => 'multipart'
            )
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";      //Exception Caught
    }
}
```

The issue is that suppose I have taken access token from a mail id and file is uploaded on that id and after that I didn't logged out from my website. I have loggedout from gmail id but access token on my website in session is present in my website and again I am uploading file than my code uploads file on previous mailid not on second id because access token on my website is present and its associated with first mail id so it uploads on first id.Please give me a solution for this issue.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Having access to GMail and having access to Drive through access tokens are different. Think of GMail as another application that you don't have control with. It has a different access token from your application. With this, if you logged out of GMail and your webapp's credentials hasn't - it will still do the intended function your webapp does (which is to upload a file to Drive).

What you can do is to logout the user on your webapp so the access token is revoked. Another user can log in, a new access token will be provided to him/her.